# Splitting Existing Partitions in SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning

I have a SQL Server table that contains over 20 billion rows, with 13 billion rows in the last partition.

The table is currently partitioned 6 ways by a "Time" field:

```
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016/2017/2018
```

The 2016/2017/2018 partition needs to be split into their own partitions so there is a 2016, 2017, 2018 partition.

How can this be done and in the process avoiding a massive log file growth? The database is in Simple Recovery and currently each partition is in a separate file group on its own set of disks.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](

      [RefNo] [nchar](7) NOT NULL,

      [DevID] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,

      [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,

      [summary] [float] NULL,

      [staging] [float] NULL,

      [position] [float] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

      [RefNo] ASC,

      [DevID] ASC,

      [Time] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 96)

)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example script to create the new yearly partitions. You may need to tweak the script for your actual partition function name and new filegroup names. This method assumes the operation is performed in a maintenance window when there are no inserts into the table and data for 2016 and later isn't needed for queries.

The summary of the steps performed by the script are:

- create new partition function and scheme like the originals
- create new aligned staging table like the original
- switch the partition containing data > 2016-01-01 into the staging table
- add 3 new partitions to the original partition function/scheme
- rebuild the staging table on the original partition with DROP_EXISTING=ON
- switch the 3 new partitions from the staging table back into the original table

There are a couple of issues with your existing table partitioning you should be aware of. Because of the `RANGE LEFT` function, datetime values that are exactly midnight on the first of the year will be placed in the wrong partition. For example, a row with `Time` value '2012-01-01T00:00:00' will be in partition 1 along with year 2011 data instead of partition 2 with the rest of year 2012 data as desired. This might not be a concern unless you purge data by partition.

Be mindful that the last partition if a `RANGE LEFT` function can never be removed. The implication is that the filegroup of the last partition is permanently part of the partition schemes that use the function. In your case, filegroup `Year6FileGroup` will always be the last filegroup of the `psYearlyPartition_Log` scheme, although it can also be used for another partition, such as for year 2016 here.

The partitions after the script is run will be as below and it is expected the last partition will be empty (assuming you have no future year data). You should create the partition for next year before the start of the year to avoid splitting a non-empty partition or avoid jumping through these hoops again.

```
+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Partition Number | Lower Boundary | Upper Boundary |   Filegroup    |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|                1 | NULL           | <= 2012-01-01  | Year1FileGroup |
|                2 | > 2012-01-01   | <= 2013-01-01  | Year2FileGroup |
|                3 | > 2013-01-01   | <= 2014-01-01  | Year3FileGroup |
|                4 | > 2014-01-01   | <= 2015-01-01  | Year4FileGroup |
|                5 | > 2015-01-01   | <= 2016-01-01  | Year5FileGroup |
|                6 | > 2016-01-01   | <= 2017-01-01  | Year6FileGroup |
|                7 | > 2017-01-01   | <= 2018-01-01  | Year7FileGroup |
|                8 | > 2018-01-01   | <= 2019-01-01  | Year8FileGroup |
|                9 | > 2019-01-01   | NULL           | Year6FileGroup |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I generally recommend a `RANGE RIGHT` function when partitioning on incremental values like datetime because the behavior is more intuitive. See [Table Partitioning Best Practices](http://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/) for this and other considerations.

```
--create identical partition function and scheme
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log_Staging(datetime) 
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES(
      '20120101'
    , '20130101'
    , '20140101'
    , '20150101'
    , '20160101'
);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log_Staging
    AS PARTITION pfYearlyPartition_Log_Staging TO (
      Year1FileGroup
    , Year2FileGroup
    , Year3FileGroup
    , Year4FileGroup
    , Year5FileGroup
    , Year6FileGroup
);

--create identical aligned staging table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log_Staging](
      [RefNo] [nchar](7) NOT NULL,
      [DevID] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,
      [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
      [summary] [float] NULL,
      [staging] [float] NULL,
      [position] [float] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Log_Staging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
      [RefNo] ASC,
      [DevID] ASC,
      [Time] ASC
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 96)
) ON psYearlyPartition_Log_Staging(Time);

--switch last partition into staging table
ALTER TABLE dbo.Log
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20170101')
    TO dbo.Log_Staging PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log_Staging('20170101');

--create new partitions for main table (assuming filegroups already exist for years 7 and 8)
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log
    NEXT USED Year6FileGroup;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log()
    SPLIT RANGE('20170101');
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log
    NEXT USED Year7FileGroup;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log()
    SPLIT RANGE('20180101');
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log
    NEXT USED Year8FileGroup;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log()
    SPLIT RANGE('20190101');

--we must specify IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF in order to use DROP_EXISTING_ON here
--but, since the original table PK index definition is unchanged, that's a non-issue
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_Log_Staging] ON dbo.Log_Staging 
(
      [RefNo] ASC,
      [DevID] ASC,
      [Time] ASC
) 
WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 96)
ON psYearlyPartition_Log(Time);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Log_Staging
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20170101')
    TO dbo.Log PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20170101');
ALTER TABLE dbo.Log_Staging
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20180101')
    TO dbo.Log PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20180101');
ALTER TABLE dbo.Log_Staging
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20190101')
    TO dbo.Log PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_Log('20190101');
```

Comment: Just a quick questions @Dan Guzman - is this process likely to grow the log file in a massive way?

Comment: @Philip, only the `CREATE INDEX` needs much log space but, since you are using the `SIMPLE` model, the operation will be minimally logged (mostly PFS and GAM changes) rather than massive (individual rows). I expect log space needs to be very roughly 10-20% of the size of your current last partition size.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Guzman, that worked a treat.  When splitting the partition with 13 billion rows, do you think that should be fairly quick?

Comment: @Philip, the `SPLIT`s and other statements in the script will be nearly instantaneous because the underlying partitions will be empty. The `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX...WITH DROP EXISTING` will take some time and depends mostly on your storage system speed. Note that the index create will only process the rows for 2016 and later, not the entire 13 billion row table. Partitions before 2016 won't be touched.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Guzman, appreciate your feedback there. Much appreciated, and that current last partition contains 13 billions row. Over 20 billion rows in the table.

Comment: @Philip, FWIW, the `CREATE INDEX` took under 3 minutes for 150M rows of test data on my PC. I think you should plan for several hours for 13 billion rows.

Comment: thanks, will do. Will see in a test environment roughly how long it will take. Back-end storage is pretty slow (No SSD), so imagine it taking a good few hours yes.